# Using Laravel Fluent how can I exclude certain rows based on an array of strings?

Tags: php, laravel, fluent

In my controller file I have this:

```
$standard_sets = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
$exclude_list = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'];
```

I'd like to exclude certain rows based on the exclude array. Something like this:

```
$query->whereIn('cards.setCode', $standard_sets)
->exclude('cards.name', $exclude_list);
```

What is the right way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `whereNotIn()`?

```
$query->whereIn('cards.setCode', $standard_sets)
      ->whereNotIn('cards.name', $exclude_list);
```